# Duals of representations of affine group schemes, in particular $\mathrm{GL}_n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory

Duals of representations of affine group schemes

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. If $G$ is a group and $V$ is a dualizable i.e. finitely generated projective $R$-module on which $G$ acts, then it is known that $G$ also acts on the dual module $V^*$ via $(g \omega)(v)=\omega(g^{-1} v)$ and that $V^*$ becomes the dual in the tensor category of representations of $G$ over $R$.

Now I wonder if there is something similar for group schemes? (This should be a special case of Prop. 1.3.4 in Hovey's *Homotopy theory for comodules over a Hopf algebroid*.) So if $G$ is an affine group scheme over $R$ and $V$ is a dualizable $R$-module on which $G$ acts (i.e. we have natural group homomorphisms $G(A) \to \mathrm{Aut}_A(V \otimes_R A)$ for commutative $R$-algebras $A$), how to construct a dual representation $V^*$?

Here is my guess: Take the dual module $V^*$. There is a group anti-homomorphism $\mathrm{Aut}_A(V \otimes_R A) \to \mathrm{Aut}_A(V^* \otimes_R A)$ which maps a linear map to its dual. The inversion map is a group anti-homomorphism $G(A) \to G(A)$. Composition yields a group homomorphism $G(A) \to \mathrm{Aut}_A(V^* \otimes_R A)$. Can someone confirm this?

Specifically, how does this look like if $G=\mathrm{GL}_n$ and $V$ is the standard representation of rank $n$ (i.e. $R^n$ with obvious action)? The underlying $R$-module of $V^*$ will be $R^n$ (just as for $V$), but the action will be some non-trivial homomorphism $\mathrm{GL}_n(A) \to \mathrm{GL}_n(A)$ - which one? Out of curiosity, is there a classification of all homomorphisms of group schemes $\mathrm{GL}_n \to \mathrm{GL}_n$?

Comment: Martin, inyour second paragraph, $G$ acts on the dual of $V$ even regardless of projectivity or finite generation, really; that it be the dual in the category of reps, of course, is another thing :-)

Comment: In your specific example, it is just the map sending a mtrix to the inverse of the transpose, no?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Do you agree with the rest?

Comment: @RghtHndSd: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object#in_a_monoidal_category

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yes, sorry for the bad question. I used google shortly after I made the comment. I need to remember to do those two in the reverse order.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, yup.